# Error when starting Streamlite in Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Streamlite in Anaconda using a previously created environment and conda recipe. As a result, I got an error -

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'streamlit.cli'
```

Neither my program nor the standard demo starts as

```
streamlite hello
```

not work.
My version streamlite according Anaconda is 1.16.0

Answer (score 1):

Fix it when:

1. Open file from \anaconda3\envs\"my env name"\Scripts called
   **streamlit-script.py**
2. Change line `from streamlit.cli import main` to `from streamlit.web.cli import main`
3. Save

Now its worked